# How to access MongoDB Atlas servce from a Flask Docker container?

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask

I dockerized my `React` + `Flask` + `Nginx` application and served it in an internal server at my work.

I used `Mongo Atlas` as the database and used `pymongo` in `Flask` to create an API.

The initial part of my flask app looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import pymongo
import json
import ssh
import OpenSSL
import pprint

application = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(application)

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://...")

db = pymongo.database.Database(client, '...')
col = pymongo.collection.Collection(db, '...')

# some parts are written as `...`
```

The `Dockerfile` for the `Flask` app looks like:

```
#Using ubuntu as our base
FROM ubuntu:latest

#Install commands in ubuntu, including pymongo for DB handling

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev build-essential


#Unsure of COPY command's purpose, but WORKDIR points to /backend
COPY . /backend
WORKDIR /backend/

RUN pip3 install --proxy <proxy_settings_for_my_workplace> -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install --proxy <proxy_settings_for_my_workplace> pymongo[srv]

ENV HTTPS_PROXY=<proxy_settings_for_my_workplace>
ENV HTTP_PROXY=<proxy_settings_for_my_workplace>

#Run order for starting up the backend
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Everything builds well and goes up. However, after it goes up, I can access the frontend part fine, but the logs for my backend shows an error that says:

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: <cluster>.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,<cluster>.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,<cluster>.mongodb.net:27017: timed out`

I am assuming this is not working because I cannot access the `Mongo Atlas` through Flask using `pymongo` I tried to add the IP of the Flask image's IP to `Mongo Atlas`'s Network Access console

[image]

But it's fairly obvious that won't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is your Mongo Atlas located?

Comment: It`s a cloud service that I use: https://cloud.mongodb.com

Comment: You will need to IP whitelist your work's internet gateway rather than anything on the docker side.